# Get link within html using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, findall

I've this piece of code :

```
        <td colspan="2" class="fc_blabla">
        <a title="Blabla" href="http://www.blabla.com/.html">Blabla</a>
    </td>
```

I need to retrieve only the link, I tried many way like :

1#

```
for link in soup.find_all("td", { "class":"fc_blabla"}):
   url = link.find("href")
   print link
```

2#

```
print soup.select(".fc_blabla > href")
```

3#

```
for link in soup.find_all("a"):
   url = link.get("href")
   print url
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
html="""
  <td colspan="2" class="fc_blabla">
        <a title="Blabla" href="http://www.blabla.com/.html">Blabla</a>
    </td>
    """

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

print(soup.find("td",attrs={"class":"fc_blabla"}).a["href"])

http://www.blabla.com/.html
```

Comment: thanks for your anwser Padraic, it works well too, I can't vote up for your post 'cause i've less than 15 reputation

Comment: @Xifeat it is exactly the same answer as your accepted answer

Comment: Yes but I can accept only one post but You have anwser first, thats right

Answer (score 4):

You were looking for "href" in the "td" tag. It is in the "a" tag.

```
import bs4
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(raw_html)
td = soup.find('td', {"class":"fc_blabla"})
print td.find("a")["href"]
```

Comment: how is this different to my answer?

Comment: Thank hooked, it works perfectly, I can retrieve all the link with your method

for link in soup.find_all("td", {"class":"fc_blabla"})
   print link.find("a")["href"]

Comment: @PadraicCunningham It's not really - I simply wasn't the "fastest gun in the west". When I clicked post, yours popped up ahead of mine. Note that mine is "slightly" more robust, it doesn't rely on the fact that the ".a" tag is the first child, rather it searches for the first "a". In this case it wouldn't make a difference, but real html isn't so nice.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Also, since you asked, I provided an explanation as to why OP's code wasn't working.

Comment: In any case thanks to the both it works, unfortunatly I can't accept two anwser..

Comment: @Xifeat I've given you an upvote to this post, as you earn more rep you'll gain more privileges on this site. Your post was good, but it could have been better - try to avoid saying things like "blah blah" and say exactly what you are talking about. Also make all code inline formated with backticks `like this`. Good luck!

Comment: @Hooked, Ok thank you for your advices, It's not so easy at the begining to avoid politeness and other "blabla" but I try !